# Store confirmation emails not working

Tags: confirmation, email-reminders, paypal-standard

Got a problem that I've had 3 developers look at, yet still no solution.

- Am using 1 step checkout and when paying with paypal standard, paypal payment confirmation email is received, but no email from store. However, customer is redirected back to store after paypal payment and given order no. and success message saying they will be sent an order confirmation email.

-Only 1 email comes through though; the paypal one.

- In the admin, the order is still classed as payment pending and 'customer not notified', with no paypal payment details given in the 'Comments History' section.

Don't know if this is a paypal issue or a magento issue.

Any idea why this happens. Been trying to solve for ages now and no luck. No one knows how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be related to your postfix/sendmail configuration, in System > Configuration > Advanced > System

Set the return path to Specified and set a valid email address in the Mail Sending Settings

That should fix it, you can also force it via your vhost config if using Apache e.g

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Standard stuff goes here

<Directory /dir/to/your/web/root>
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fuser@domain2.com"
</Directory>
```

You can also check your mail.log /var/log/mail.log or use the mailq command to see what's happening with the emails.

Some ISP providers like AOL will reject emails if the proper PTR records are not set up for the website/server, so your server IP should resolve to your domain.

My advice would be to install the free MageMonkey plugin and use Mandrill for all your emails.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-integration.html